# Delete principal data if dependent data is deleted in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have the next schema:

[image]

In my business logic BomItem (or Season) relates to CommentContainer as ONE-TO-ONE. And I want to delete appropriate CommentContainer with comments if I delete BomItem (or Season).

Can I do it using EF Configuration?

How can I do it by the best way?

Comment: a few more details could be helpful, EF Version, SQL Server Version, database first, code first, ...? As far as I know there is no EF Configuration to delete a principal entity. Your best start to handle that in code would be to override SaveChanges on your DbContext. On the database end you could use a delete trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Add a foreign key in CommentContainer of table BomItem. Also, make it Cascade on Delete.

Now when you delete a row in BomItem, the corresponding row in CommentContainer (linked with the primary key of BomItem) will be deleted.
Same relationship can be developed between CommentContainer and Comment table.

ON DELETE CASCADE referential action for a foreign key deletes data automatically from the child tables when you delete data from the parent table.